# Can we have different app graphics for beta build and production build on android play store?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Can we have different app icon, banner, app video and all other graphics that are shown on play store for a beta build that is recently uploaded and production build that is serving live on play store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. All Play store attributes will be served to all build types.

You can use "Store Listing Experiments" to change these icons and videos etc. for a subset of users but you cannot target those to specific builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can define different flavors in your app's build.gradle, then create alternative resources for each one using the **New Resource File** dialog and selecting the **Source set** for your intended flavor.

```
android {
.....
productFlavors {
    flavorDimensions "releaseType"
    beta {
        dimension "releaseType"
        .....
    }
    beta {
        dimension 'releaseType'
        ......
    }
}
.....
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I am asking about the play store listing

Answer (score -1):

Simply add debug/res/whatever-you-want under your src folder.
Debug builds will use this resources, instead of default ones.

[image]

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I am asking about the play store listing.